# decode drivers license PDF417 or magnetic strip

Tags: .net, vb.net, scanning, pdf417, magnetic-cards

I was able to extract the code from the barcode but when reading the magnetic script from a OHIO drivers license I cannot seem to get the two letter code that prefixes the license number like the PDF417 does.

```vb
Private Sub ScannDLButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ScanDLButton.Click
        Try


            Dim strInputBox As String = InputBox("Please Swipe/Scan Customer's Driver's License", "Driver's License")

            Dim strLastName As String
            Dim strFirstName As String
            Dim strMiddleName As String
            Dim strDOB As String
            Dim strStreet As String
            Dim strCity As String
            Dim strState As String
            Dim strZIP As String
            Dim strDL As String
            Dim strCountry As String
```

this determines if it is a magnetic strip

```
            If strInputBox.Contains("%") Then

                Dim CaretPresent As Boolean = False
                Dim EqualPresent As Boolean = False
                CaretPresent = strInputBox.Contains("^")
                EqualPresent = strInputBox.Contains("=")

                If CaretPresent Then 'track one
                    Dim CardData As String() = strInputBox.Split("^"c)
                    strState = CardData(0).Substring(1, 2)
                    strCity = CardData(0).Substring(3, CardData(0).Length - 3)
                    Dim strname As String() = CardData(1).Split("$"c)
                    strLastName = strname(0)
                    strFirstName = strname(1)
                    strMiddleName = strname(2)
                    strStreet = CardData(2)
                    Dim strzipcode As String() = CardData(3).Split("+"c)
                    strZIP = strzipcode(1).Substring(2, 5)

                End If

                If EqualPresent Then ' track two
                    Dim CardData As String() = strInputBox.Split("="c)
                    strDOB = CardData(1).Substring(6, 6)

                End If
```

this determines if the user scanned a barcode on back of the license

```
            ElseIf strInputBox.Contains("ANSI") Then

                Dim separatingStrings As String() = {"ANSI", "DBA", "DCS", "DAC", "DAD", "DBD", "DBB", "DBC", "DAY", "DAU", "DAG", "DAI", "DAJ", "DAK", "DAQ", "DCF", "DCG", "DDE", "DDF", "DDG", "DAZ", "DCI", "DCJ", "DCU", "DCE", "DDA", "DDB", "DAW", "DDK", "ZOZ", "ZOE"}
                Dim text As String = strInputBox
                Dim words As String() = text.Split(separatingStrings, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                Dim i As Integer = 0

                For Each word In words
                    _log.Info("Looking at code: " & separatingStrings(i).ToString)
                    _log.Info("Parsing field: " & word.ToString.Trim)
                    strLastName = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DCS", word.ToString.Trim, strLastName)
                    strFirstName = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAC", word.ToString.Trim, strFirstName)
                    strMiddleName = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAD", word.ToString.Trim, strMiddleName)
                    strDOB = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DBB", word.ToString.Trim, strDOB)
                    strStreet = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAG", word.ToString.Trim, strStreet)
                    strCity = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAI", word.ToString.Trim, strCity)
                    strState = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAJ", word.ToString.Trim, strState)
                    strZIP = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAK", word.ToString.Trim, strZIP)
                    strDL = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DAQ", word.ToString.Trim, strDL)
                    strCountry = IIf(separatingStrings(i) = "DCG", word.ToString.Trim, strCountry)
                    i += 1
                Next

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect format, contact us with this type of ID", "Scan Driver's License", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                Return
            End If
```

Is there code encrypted code within the text line.

Comment: A sample input string would help.

Comment: You don't need to call `.ToString` on variables that are already strings.

Comment: Here is a sample `%OHCINCINNATI^KING$JUSTIN$FREDERIC$^1616 SOMER DR^?;6360231911247481=200419730405?+10451401875  D A         M   1509170BROBRO                          @7#/F+     ?`

Comment: Since the sample you provided sample you provided contained % and ^ I could only test track one which worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but maybe someone will still find this answer helpful.

It appears, at least for Ohio, that the two letter license number prefix is represented by the ordinal number of the alphabet (A=01 .. Z=26).

So in the sample data ";6360231911247481"
the "636023" is Ohio's ANSI Id prefix and
"19" is the ordinal of the first letter ("S") and
"11" is the ordinal of the second letter ("K"),
with "247481" being the remaining numeric portion.

So for this example, the full DL Number is "SK247481".

Note that this was determined from sample data and not a documented source, so ymmv.